# Insert more than one pair in c++

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I have a map like this:

```
map<string, map<int, int>> collector;
```

And I have no idea how to insert data in my map. If I had

```
map<string, int> collector;
```

with only key-value I would use

```
collector.insert(pair<string, int>)(name,money));
```

But what is the way of inserting when we have map in map.  I tried to do:

```
typedef map<int, int> map_;
  for(iteration = collector.begin(); iteration != collector.end(); iteration++) {
    iteration = collector.find(word);
    if(iteration == collector.end()) {
        iteration = collector.insert(map_::value_type(num,num).first;
    }
}
```

This way is not working for me.

Comment: Can you use C++11 features?

Comment: First of all, your code has syntax errors. What is the error you get?

Comment: i just posted a little bit of my code, i am trying to get the idea how to insert data into my map.

Comment: `colector[a_string][a_int] = b_int;`

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ways to insert into your data structure:

```
#include <iostream>  // cout
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <utility>  // make_pair

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    using Collector = map<string, map<int, int>>;

    Collector collector;

    collector["USD"] = Collector::mapped_type{ { 1, 3 }, { 0, 8 } };

    collector["EUR"].insert(make_pair(4, 5));
    collector["EUR"].insert(make_pair(6, 7));

    collector["CHF"][2] = 4;

    const Collector::mapped_type jpyIntegers { { 10, 20 }, { 100, 200 } };

    collector.insert(make_pair("JPY", jpyIntegers));

    collector["MMK"];

    for (const auto& a: collector) {
        cout << a.first << ": ";
        for (const auto& i: a.second) {
            cout << "(" << i.first << "|" << i.second << ")";
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
```